# how to distribute the weight of a point among the vertices of a square in which it lies?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, algorithms, euclidean-algorithm

I want to do soft-binning for a distance-based histogram. For example a point X lies somewhere between the center points of 4 bins, A,B,C,D. These four points A,B,C,D can be treated as the vertices of a square.

I would like to assign each of these vertex points a certain weightage (between 0-1) based how much the point X is closer to that vertex with two conditions:

- Sum of all vertex weights should be 1.
- If X lies on the line between two vertices, only those two vertices should get the share in weightage.

Currently I calculate the weightage as:

```
W(A) = (1 - distance of A from X/sum of distances of all vertices from X )/3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do [bilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation).  For a point $(x,y)$in the unit square, the weight at $(0,0)$ is $(1-x)(1-y)$, the weight at $(1,0)$ is $x(1-y)$ and so on.  The weights sum to $1$ and are zero when the point is on the opposite edge of the square.

Comment: Since my actual problem is in 3D. I was considering to use trilinear interpolation. But it seemed that all its implementations require weights at the vertices as input and outputs weight at the point X. 

Would you know of a reverse implementation in python or C++?

Comment: You can just expand this by one dimension.  The weight of $(x,y,z)$ at $(0,0,0)$ is $(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)$.  For each corner the factor is the variable if the component is $1$ and $(1-$ the variable) if the component is $0$.  Basically you are doing linear interpolation in each axis and multiplying the results.